# rbind txt files from online directory (R)

Tags: r, concatenation, rbind, stringr

I am trying to get concatenate text files from url but i don't know how to do this with the html and the different folders?

This is the code i tried, but it only lists the text files and has a lot of html code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Z1L.png) How do I fix this so that I can combine the text files into one csv file?

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "http://weather.ggy.uga.edu/data/daily/"
dir <- getURL(url, dirlistonly = T)
filenames <- unlist(strsplit(dir,"\n")) #split into filenames
#append the files one after another
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
file <- past(url,filenames[i],delim='') #concatenate for urly 
if (i==1){
cp <- read_delim(file, header=F, delim=',')
}
else{
temp <- read_delim(file,header=F,delim=',')
cp <- rbind(cp,temp) #append to existing file
rm(temp)# remove the temporary file
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code snippet that I got to work for me. I like to use rvest over RCurl, just because that's what I've learned. In this case, I was able to use the `html_nodes` function to isolate each file ending in .txt. The result table has the times saved as character strings, but you could fix that later. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
library(rvest)
library(readr)

url <- "http://weather.ggy.uga.edu/data/daily/"

doc <- xml2::read_html(url)
text <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(doc, "tr td a:contains('.txt')"))


# define column types of fwf data ("c" = character, "n" = number)
ctypes <- paste0("c", paste0(rep("n",11), collapse = ""))
data <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:2){
  file <- paste0(url, text[1])

  date <- as.Date(read_lines(file, n_max = 1), "%m/%d/%y")

  # Read file to determine widths
  columns <- fwf_empty(file, skip = 3)

  # Manually expand `solar` column to be 3 spaces wider
  columns$begin[8] <- columns$begin[8] - 3

  data <- rbind(data, cbind(date,read_fwf(file, columns, 
                                          skip = 3, col_types = ctypes)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi, For some reason column 9 (Solar) does not have the correct values. It only has the last digit. That's the only column it affected. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That seems to be an issue with `fwf_empty`, a function that determines the column ends and beginnings.  I've created a manual fix that isn't ideal but should work for you.